# How can i use a Library for another Library ? [Arduino ESP32]

Tags: arduino-c++, arduino-esp32

I am working on a project on Arduino ESP32 and I have a lot of Global variables (for data generation). I have decided to create a library in order to orgenise my work a little better. But I use this library into other librari's that I had to create for other usage. after compilation it I have the following error :

```
sketch\OX2inj_LEVEL_OX2.cpp.o:(.data.addrChipId+0x0): multiple definition of `addrChipId'
sketch\First_Useage.cpp.o:(.data.addrChipId+0x0): first defined here
sketch\OX2inj_LEVEL_OX2.cpp.o:(.bss.ChipID+0x0): multiple definition of `ChipID'
sketch\First_Useage.cpp.o:(.bss.ChipID+0x0): first defined here
```

here is my `.ino` (main) code :

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "Var_Str_EEPROM.h"
#include "Def_Global_Var.h"
#include "First_Useage.h"

//---------somthing

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //---------somthing
  Serial.println(ChipID.ReadStrEEPROM());
  //---------somthing

}

void loop() 
{
  //---------somthing
}
```

here is my `"Def_Global_Var.h"` code

```
#ifndef Def_Global_Var_H
#define Def_Global_Var_H

#include "Var_Str_EEPROM.h"


uint16_t addrChipId = 1;

VarStrEEPROM ChipID(addrChipId);

#endif
```

here is my `"First_Useage.h"` code

```
 #ifndef First_Usage_H
#define First_Usage_H

void getchipid();

#endif
```

here is my `"First_Useage.cpp"` code :

```
#include "First_Useage.h"
#include <Arduino.h>

#include "Var_Str_EEPROM.h"
#include "Def_Global_Var.h"

void getchipid()
{
  uint32_t chipId = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<17; i=i+8) 
    chipId |= ((ESP.getEfuseMac() >> (40 - i)) & 0xff) << i;
  ChipID.WriteStrEEPROM(String(chipId));
}
```

My understanding is that, when I use the #include `"Def_Global_Var.h"`, the programme thinks that : "I am calling the library" and it sees that it has been called before and it does not like it.
***Is it somehow correct ? and if it is(or not) correct what should I do?***

EDIT : sorry I have put the wrong part of the prog. it has been corrected now

Answer (score 0):

The actual cause is that the header is included into several source files, so you end up with multiple conflicting definitions of these variables in your `.o` files.

You shouldn't normally define global variables in header files at all; you should only *declare* them as `extern`:

```
#ifndef Def_Global_Var_H
#define Def_Global_Var_H
...
extern uint16_t addrChipId;
...
#endif
```

The second step is to define the variable in the corresponding `.cpp` file, this time without the `extern` keyword:

```
// Def_Global_Var.cpp

uint16_t addrChipId = 1;
```

Since `Def_Global_Var.o` gets linked only once, there should be no more conflicts.

Comment: OR since this is C++, and it doesn't look like `addrChipID` is actually modified, OP could declare it `constexpr`.

Comment: So you are saing that I can not use a "global variable Library".

thank you . I will find another solution in that case.
@Spencer : the problem is that I need to take information from libraries that I have created and in these libraries I have to be able to change these information too.

Comment: I'm not saying that at all. You can put global variables into a library, you just have to write it correctly to avoid duplicates.